# b.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an AngularJS form, I have the restriction of not editing the already developed code, Now I have to add pre-populated default values to each field of the form.

I am trying to select form with

```
var x  = $(".form-group");
```

Loop through the form for each child elements

```
var x  = $(".form-group")
$(x).each((index, value) => console.log(value.children))
```

I will put default values to an array

```
var defaulttext = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
```

then assign values to fields as

```
$(value.children).val(value);
```

Below is the full code:

```js
var x  = $(".form-group");
var defaulttext = ["yogeesh", "yogeesh@gmail.com", "88616649678"];

$(x).each(defaulttext , function (index, value){
  $(element.children).val(defaulttext[index]);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<form>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputdefault">Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputlg">Email ID</label>
      <input class="form-control input-lg" id="inputlg" type="text">
    </div>
 
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputlg">Phone Number</label>
      <input class="form-control input-lg" id="inputlg" type="text">
    </div>
    
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But I am getting an error in the console as:
b.apply is not a function

Comment: Can't solve without further details.

Comment: The argument to `.each()` should just be a function, what is `numbers` doing there?

Comment: What is x? And what do you want to do? Describe a little more your problem. By the way `each` condition is wrong. Probably the problem is there. Or you write `$.each(array, function())` or `$(array).each(function())`

Comment: check out this please https://jsfiddle.net/yogeeshsj/he2ctcho/

Comment: You say *AngularJS form* but your fiddle (I've put this into your question) doesn't include or reference any angular?

Comment: I have added AngularJS in question its a problem statement, since it has component and so much code, So I created code snippet of what actually I need, Is it right ..? https://jsfiddle.net/yogeeshsj/he2ctcho/

Comment: Instead of posting fiddle after fiddle, please edit the question to include all the code required to re-create your problem

Comment: Also that fiddle **is identical** to the last 4 you posted on this question!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to mix two things:

```
$(x).each(callback)
```

which iterates over the DOM elements in `$(x)`, and

```
$.each(defaulttext, callback)
```

which iterates over the array. You can't do them both in one call.

`$(x).each()` just takes one argument, a callback function. You can't put `defaulttext` in there before the function, it will try to use that array as the callback.

However, the first argument to the callback is an index, so you can use that to refer to the other thing you want to access.

```js
var x = $(".form-group");
var defaulttext = ["yogeesh", "yogeesh@gmail.com", "88616649678"];

$(x).each(function(index, value) {
  $(value).children().val(defaulttext[index]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputdefault">Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputlg">Email ID</label>
    <input class="form-control input-lg" id="inputlg" type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputlg">Phone Number</label>
    <input class="form-control input-lg" id="inputlg" type="text">
  </div>

</form>
```

Also, `children` is a jQuery method, so you should call it on the result of `$(element)`, not inside the call.

And you don't need to write `$(x)`. `x` is already a jQuery object, you don't need to call `$()` again, that will just make a new copy of the object.

Comment: Hi, @Barmar I have detailed the question can you please re-face the answer

Comment: I don't see any change except that `numbers` is now called `defaulttext`. The answer is the same.

Comment: Why should I check that? It's still doing it the wrong way. I've shown you the correct code.

Comment: Why do you insist on putting `defaulttext` as the first argument to `$(x).each()`?

Comment: Getting error callback is not a function https://jsfiddle.net/yogeeshsj/he2ctcho/

Comment: @Liam I've been here for 6 or 7 years, that's the first time I've actually lost it and called a poster a name like that.

Comment: nop @Barmer, I am unable to find a solution so I added a question, It will be great if you check this link https://jsfiddle.net/yogeeshsj/he2ctcho/ and correct me, sorry for not understanding your answer, since you are more experienced, I am new to javascript so you may felt I am stupid

Comment: He man, you tried. @YOGEESH Bramar has given you a lot of good stuff here, time to engage your brain and do some additional thinking for yourself here, "you can lead a horse to water but you can't make it think"

Comment: @Liam, Great quote But what if the Horse has a mouth infection unable to open it, and it will get cured over the period

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barmer & Liam, I will get well soon